Teaching my university course on Udemy
I am an assistant Professor at a university and I am actually teaching there a specific course in finance. The materials are mine:  I am the only responsable of this course, it is me who created the content, and I am teaching the course alone.
While I am an assistant professor at the university, I am thinking to start my own business on Udemy in order to earn more money. Is it legal for me that I start teaching on Udemy the same course that I am giving at the university?
I would appreciate any suggestions.

You need to contact your university to investigate this.  Your institution's policies prevail.  It's definitely not as straightforward as you think.  They may have policies limiting your total time commitment to other things (consulting, another business, etc). If they do allow it, then they may also require you to do things a certain way, report things in systems, etc.  Absolutely do not move forward without being fully transparent.  These things can have major consequences if people find out later.  It burns a lot of bridges that you weren't upfront about something that could be managed.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin Thank you a lot for your comment. Yeah I will see that with the HR!

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin suggest writing that as an answer.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin. -  no.  Your idea is not bad, but the poster should start with their own representation, who should be skilled in education.

Don't just check with HR, read the details of your hiring contract. It's possible it contains claims on what you've written, regardless of whether that would hold up in court. You need to know the current situation first before you can look for change.

It's not uncommon to have rules against teaching for any other organization.

This is a matter of contract. I suspect that it is mentioned (and forbidden) in your contract, but you need to examine it yourself, or discuss it with HR. A colleague of mine was fired for trying to teach at two places with "their" materials.
It is fairly common for universities to claim rights on some materials created by their faculty as the faculty are employees, not contractors. The same would be true if you were working at a place like IBM or Google. Your work product may belong to your employer.
Read the contract.
It could even be, depending on where you are, that there are civil laws governing work product of employees and its transferability. If you want to start a "business" you need to talk to a lawyer.

Thank you Dr. Buffy for all these information. I appreciate a lot.

I would just point out that there is a difference between "outside activities" and using the same materials to sell.  It could be that your institution allows you to sell Udemy courses, but you are not allowed to use the same content.  They may require that the content does not substantially overlap to ensure something doesn't happen in error.  This is why you have to inquire.  I work at an R1, and the faculty have tons of side businesses.  It's very normal in applied research.  It's no fun to manage on our side, but we do it--carefully.  There are rules, but the answer isn't "absolutely not".

This may help sharpen the concept that the university owns your work.  There was a case in 2021 where the university sold online courses taught by a deceased professor.  It was obviously very controversial, but it does highlight the fact that universities can own your class materials and use them even after you die.  You should check the policies to know what you are bound to.
https://slate.com/technology/2021/01/dead-professor-teaching-online-class.html

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin Yeah I see! very important comments from your part. Probably in this case I would rather talk to the university director to see the situation with him and allow me under some possible constraints.

@AhmadBitar That seems smart, particularly if you are not yet very senior. Here in Sweden the university explicitly does not own any IPR to any material we produce, but I would still recommend everybody to have a prior discussion before going ahead with selling what is effectively an online copy of the university course. They are still your employer, and they still have lots of ways to make your life difficult if they do not like what you are doing (outside of IPR challenges).
